# Why isn't the radio button in my Django template form displaying on the screen?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm following a tutorial on Django's official site (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial04/), everything went fine until I came to the part where they had me create an html form using Django templates, here's the template and form (namely, detail.html):

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
<ul>
<!--{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
       <li>{{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
{% endfor %}-->
<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li>{{ choice.choice_text }}</li>
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text}}</label><br />
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
      {% endfor %}
 <input type="submit" value="Vote" />
 </form>
 </ul>

     {% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}
```

Here's the view:

```
def detail(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {'question': question})
```

The part where I start to get problems is at the radio button (in template), it doesn't display on the screen at all, here's the output:

[image: Html Form]

I tried rearanging the code a little in hope that there might be a syntax error, then I tried finding the solution by watching tutorials on youtube but no success, come somebody help me?

Comment: I guess there is no data in `question.choice_set.all`, the loop is not executing, not only radio button, label text is also not visible. just make sure you are getting objects of choices

Comment: Use [How to debug small programs (#3)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to check if you got data to create the boxes in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

I had what is probably the same issue.

I had skipped this part: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api

This is where you use the API/Python shell to add the voting choices manually via the command line.

Comment: Me too, they really should include a pointer to say that this is important as something described as playing with the API doesnt seem to be mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

**Theory:**
I just explain the following row, before I get to the mistake.

```
 {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
```

`question`: selected ID of the question you chose in the URL http://localhost:8000/polls/1/ --> **1**

`.choice_set`: is a query on table `polls_choice` and because of the fact, that in the tutorial a foreign key on Choice was created, the related entry for ID = 1 can be found.

`.all`: means that each entry with the related foreign key will be used.

**Resolving:**
I think, you skipped the part of tutorial 02 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial02/ , where you have to create an table entry for polls_choice. [Create_table_entry_polls_choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6BFH.png) . That is why the for loop is not running, because there are no entries. Just repeat that, or create the entries manual in your MYSQL database or whatever you use.